# $\{ P_3, P_4 \}$-factor

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory, factorization

**Definition.** A graph $G=(V,E)$ is  to be $\{d_1,\dots,d_n\}$-graph if for each vertex $v\in V$ we have $\text{deg}(v)=d_i$ for  some $i=1,\dots n$.

**Definition.**  A connected graph $G=(V,E)$ is called $n$-connected (for n\geq 2) whenever if we remove $n-1$ vertices then the graph is still  connected.

**Definition.** A $P_k$-factor of a graph $G=(V,E)$ is a spanning subgraph of $G$ such that each component of which is $P_k$, the path on $k$ vertices. We say that $G$ has a $P_k$-factorization if $E$ can be partitioned into $P_k$-factors

**Question.** Let $G=(V,E)$ be a $\{2,3\}$-graph which is also 2-connected and $|V|>5$. Does $G$ have $\{ P_3, P_4 \}$-factor?

Comment: How about a triangle?  Gerhard "Thinking About Very Small Counterexamples" Paseman, 2018.09.06.

Comment: @GerhardPaseman: Perhaps the OP intends that a $\{2,3\}$ graph must have at least one vertex of deg-$2$ and at least one of deg-$3$? Under this interpretation, a triangle is a $\{2\}$-graph.

Comment: The [Ear decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ear_decomposition) may be helpful.

Comment: What is a $\{P_3,P_4\}$-factor?

Answer (score 3):

I cannot think of a proof or disproof at the moment but in 'Path factors in cubic graphs', Kawarabayashi, Matsuda and Oda proved that every 2-connected cubic graph of order at least six has a {$P_3$,$P_4$}-factor. (Actually, they showed that every such graph has a {$P_k$| $k$≥6}-factor.) I am not sure you can renounce the implicit minimum degree condition and still hope for the same conclusion.